# PayPal certificate invalid or not found

Tags: certificate, paypal

For the last couple of days, I have been working on realising a payment integration using the PayPal SDK for PHP (which uses the REST API). However, I have been experiencing some issues.

When a payer is redirected to the PayPal site for approving his payment and redirected back to the return URL, PayPal returns a HTTP 400 status code upon executing the approved payment. The code for executing the payment is as follows. Note that $paymentId is the ID returned after creating the payment and $payerId is the PayerID sent along with the approval.

```
$payment = Payment::get($paymentId);
$paymentExecution = new PaymentExecution();
$paymentExecution->setPayer_id($payerId);
$payment->execute($paymentExecution);
```

It says the payment is invalid:

> {"name":"PAYMENT_STATE_INVALID","message":"This request is invalid due to the current state of the payment","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#PAYMENT_STATE_INVALID","debug_id":"223647e6e42fb"}

While figuring out where all goes wrong (note that the samples included with the API also give the same error), I stumbled across the following line in my log files:

> PPHttpConnection: Invalid or no certificate authority found - Retrying using bundled CA certs file

I checked to make sure that the SDK locates the certificate included with the SDK. So my guess is that it's an invalid certificate. I'm kind of lost now about what to do. Does anybody have an idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Make sure the `payment_id` and `payer_id` are correct. Refer https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#execute-an-approved-paypal-payment

Comment: My bad, pointed to the wrong response from PayPal. Post edited. Error occurs not on the response that is received after PayPal has approved the payment. It pops up when trying to execute the payment.

Comment: This may happen, when you send more then one execute payment request for the sample payment, so check for any duplicate statements(`$payment->execute($paymentExecution);`). The certificate problem is just a warning, the SDK will retry the request with bundled CA certs file.

Comment: Checked for multiple execute statements. The payment is only being executed once.

About the certificate issue: when I turn off the certificate verification using this code `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);` the payment does actually achieve the status completed and no PPConnectionException is thrown. However, it isn't a viable solution due to safety measures.

Answer (score 0):

You should always check your payments `state` before running an execute. The error indicates that the payment already was executed

> Payment state. Must be set to one of the one of the following:
>   `created; approved; failed; canceled; expired; pending`.  Value assigned
>   by PayPal.

You probably ran the method `Create` on your payment, and the `Create` method executes the same submethods as `Execute`.